# Is there a plugin--omnicomplete or other-- that will suggest python modules to import?

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

For example:

```
from datetime import <c-x><c-o>{list of modules inside datetime package}
```

Comment: I can't help thinking of Clippy ... "Hi! It looks like you're trying to calculate the number of days between two dates. Have you tried datetime.timedelta?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only plugin that claims support for it right now is [pysmell](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/10/13/pysmell-v06-released/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) to have omnicompletion for python modules.